# Can I use nHibernate with monotouch?

Tags: iphone, nhibernate, xamarin.ios

Did anyone tried out to use nHibernate with monotouch framework? Are there any issues that I should take in concern? Or this scenario is not possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not possible and why would you want to anyway!? far far far too clunky.

alternatives made for the job:

sqlite-net: http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-net/

entify: http://code.google.com/p/entify/

Comment: I didn't know about this entify. Nice project.